# changing svg element attribute using javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, html, web

I was practising web programming when i encountered this problem. 
The problem is that when i try to repeatedly increment the radius of the circle in the for loop, it does not show the result of change after each iteration,though it displays the result on the last iteration i.e. when i reaches 40, the circle with radius 40 is displayed. So what's the problem here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function strokeincr(){
var circl = document.getElementById("circ");
var i;
for(i=10;i<=40;i++)
{
alert("for i="+i);//this was just to see the value of i changing.
            circl.setAttribute("r",i);
       }
    }

</script>

<style>
    #div1 svg{
        width:200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color:pink;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="div1">
<svg>
  <circle id="circ" cx="100" cy="100" r="10" fill="green"></circle>
</svg>
</div> 
<button onclick="strokeincr()"> click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, firstly the alert stops processes, but more importantly the `for loop` tells the program to run the code between it's braces and it will do so as quickly and efficiently as it can. As @YonaAppletree pointed out, though not written within the official specification, most all Browsers(if not all) implement the same or trivially different processing rules, and will not allow a repaint of the view during a for loop. This is an optimization to conserve resources, and really it doesn't make much difference from an end-user perspective since, even if it didn't do this, the code would most often be processed faster than the human eye could discern. This means it's a good optimization, but it also means that your current code won't work how you expect it to.

What we can do is setup an interval timer that will clear itself after `i` becomes equal to 40 or greater. An interval takes two parameters

`setInterval( function , time in ms )`

`ms` is milliseconds. 1000 ms is equal to 1 second. The function provided will be repeated over and over at the specified interval until the interval is cleared. For Example:

`setInterval( function() { console.log("hi!") }, 1000)`

will print "hi!" to your console every 1000 ms, which is equivalent to 1 second. This will never stop because it never clears.

By assigning this function to a variable we make sure that we can clear it(stop the function) once `i` reaches 40 or greater.

This is how you assign an interval to a variable:

`var myIntervalTimer = setInterval(function, time in ms)`

to clear that interval you call `clearInterval( name of interval )`. For Example:

`clearInterval(myIntervalTimer)`

Then we just plug it into your already established code, and voila!

```
var i = 10;
var myIntervalTimer = setInterval(function() {
             console.log("i is" + i);
            circl.setAttribute("r",i);
            if(i >= 40) clearInterval(myIntervalTimer);
            i++;
}, 250);
```

We now have a timer that will increase the radius of the circle every quarter second(250ms) and will clear the interval timer if `i` is ever equal to 40 or greater.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function strokeincr(){
var circl = document.getElementById("circ");
var i = 10;
var myIntervalTimer = setInterval(function() {
            circl.setAttribute("r",i);
            if(i >= 40) clearInterval(myIntervalTimer);
            i++;
}, 250);
}
</script>

<style>
    #div1 svg{
        width:200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color:pink;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="div1">
<svg>
  <circle id="circ" cx="100" cy="100" r="10" fill="green"></circle>
</svg>
</div> 
<button onclick="strokeincr()"> click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The solution is correct, but I think it misses, somewhat, the thinking behind _why_ it's correct. The circle is not redrawn "Faster, even, then you can see." Nor is the program in the solution running slower "than it can" as it were. In fact, the circle only updated once in the original code, after the for loop is done processing. Browsers are event based. Some event happens, like a click or timed event. It then runs the associated handler code. Then it recomputes the view and update the screen. Then it waits for more events.

Comment: @YonaAppletree You're correct about repainting and I'll update my speed explanation accordingly. I was never trying to imply that the code in an interval was running "slower than it could", just that the aforementioned function was being run at a specified delay.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here has to do with how browsers update the screen and how events work. Browsers have something called an "event loop." The browser waits for some event to happen, like the user clicking on your button, and then it executes the associated code. Calls that modify the document, like your setAttribute call, don't directly cause the screen to update. Rather, they are updating the DOM (Document Object Model) that defines what the browser should display to the screen.

Only after all event handling code is finished, does the screen get updated. So, you loop from 10 to 40, updating the radius of the circle. But the browser only bothers to check the value after your loop has finished. So you only see the final value.

As mentioned in @zfrisch's answer, one way to solve this is to use the event scheduling features of the browser. These features allow you to ask the browser to fire an event (and handle it with code of your choosing) at some later time.

There are three main scheduling functions available to you: `setTimeout(callback, delayInMs)`, `setInterval(callback, intervalInMs)`, and `requestAnimationFrame(callback)`. You can look up the documentation for them for further explanation, but in general, for animation you should use `requestAnimationFrame`.

`requestAnimationFrame` basically asks the browser to execute some code later, after it has rendered everything and is ready to render something new.

Using `requestAnimationFrame`, your example might look something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function strokeincr() {
      // Note the use of const instead of var. It indicates a variable that we won't change, and ensures that we don't change it.
    
      const circl = document.getElementById("circ");
      
      // We need to know how long our animation should last, so we can compute where we are.
      // Note that since the varaible contains milliseconds, we label it as such for clarity.
      const animationDurationMs = 1000;
      
      // The starting time of the animation (in milliseconds since the epoch), so we can compute where we are in the animation later.
      const startTimeMs = Date.now();
      
      // Define the starting and ending values for the animation for later computation
      const startRadius = 10;
      const endRadius = 40;
      
      function incrementAnimation() {
        // Get the now-current time so we can compute the animation progress
        const currentTimeMs = Date.now();
        
        // Compute where we are in the animation as a fraction, ensuring we don't go over 1, using Math.min
        const animationFraction = Math.min(
            1,
            (currentTimeMs - startTimeMs) / animationDurationMs
          );
        
        // Compute what the current radius should be, given where we are in the animation, using liner interpolation
        const currentRadius = startRadius + (endRadius - startRadius) * animationFraction;
        
        // Update the circle with the new radius
        circl.setAttribute("r", currentRadius);
        
        // Check if there is more animating to do, and if so, request that this function is run again after the screen is updated.
        if (animationFraction < 1)
          requestAnimationFrame(incrementAnimation);
      }
      
      // Start the animation by calling the animation function directly.
      incrementAnimation();
    }
  </script>

  <style>
    #div1 svg {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: pink;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div1">
    <svg>
      <circle id="circ" cx="100" cy="100" r="10" fill="green"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <button onclick="strokeincr()">click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire loop is executed when you click the button. If you want to increment the radius of the circle each time you click the button, you have to take a different approach.

```
function strokeincr() {
    var circl = document.getElementById("circ");
    var r = parseInt(circl.getAttribute("r"));
    circl.setAttribute("r", r + 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a very interesting question you have there. I will try to answer it the best I can.

You ran into unexpected behaviour that exists, due to browser optimisations. It has to do with repainting. You are changing the radius of the circle every step of the loop. If the browser had to repaint the screen for every iteration, that would be a very demanding operation.

So what did the browser vendors do? They (apparently) delayed the repaint until after the loop is finished. Makes sense right?

This suddenly became visible as you started using the alert to pause the loop (note how the value in the DOM does change on every iteration, but the screen doesn't repaint).

If you want to animate this change there are several approaches. You can use css transitions or use JavaScripts `window.requestAnimationFrame()`. But that is beyond the scope of your question ;).

PS: This answer is based on my own observations and some articles I read a while ago, so do comment if you know some official documentation about this repainting behaviour (I am kinda curious about it myself).